# Через некоторое время престаёт работать бот VK API python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Написал бота, используя VK API python. Бот запускается и корректно работает, но через некоторое время бездействия перестаёт отвечать, а после выдаётся ошибка:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера', None, 10060, None))

**Код:**
https://github.com/Fedos-py/bot_for_overflow/blob/main/bot

**Полная ошибка:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
File "", line 3, in raise_from
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1336, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 267, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
timeout=timeout
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 403, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
chunked=chunked,
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
six.raise_from(e, None)
File "", line 3, in raise_from
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1336, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 306, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 267, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера', None, 10060, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/FEDJA/PycharmProjects/bot_vk/bot_group.py", line 123, in 
name = bot_api.users.get(user_id=event.object.from_id)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 681, in **call**
return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 612, in method
values
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 578, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\FEDJA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера', None, 10060, None))

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Не сильно вникая но кажется вы не обработали исключение с разрывом связи. в этой строке `name = bot_api.users.get(user_id=event.object.from_id)`

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll?f=1.%20Подключение
wait — время ожидания (так как некоторые прокси-серверы обрывают соединение после 30 секунд, мы рекомендуем указывать wait=25). Максимальное значение — 90.